# Is there a compatibility problem with these RAM modules at different speeds?

Tags: motherboard, memory, desktop, compatibility

I'm planning to update some components on my PC and I want to know if I can buy two more modules of RAM without compatibility issues.

This is the new motherboard I will be buying, a [Gigabyte B365M-DS3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B365M-DS3H-rev-10#kf). It has 4 slots for RAM; now, I only have 2 on my [Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2H](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H110M-S2H-rev-10#ov).

I want to buy the two remaining RAM modules and go for the 32GB of RAM (8GB x4) because sometimes 16GB is small for my work. Currently I have two `HyperX Fury DDR4 2133 C14 8GB` (CPU-Z says: DDR4-2134, Part number KHX2133C14D4/8GB) and I'm wondering if I could buy a pack of two of any of these newer models:

- `Kingston HyperX Fury Black DDR4 2400Mhz PC-19200 2x8GB CL15`
- `Kingston HyperX Fury Black DDR4 2666Mhz PC-21300 2x8GB CL16`
- `Kingston HyperX Fury Black DDR4 3200Mhz PC-25600 2x8GB CL16` (Too fast for the motherboard?)
- `Kingston HyperX Fury Black DDR4 3466Mhz PC-27700 2x8GB CL16` (Too fast for the motherboard?)

My concern is that even though the new motherboard supports 2666/2400/2133 MHz, my older RAM runs at 2133MHz and it will be different compared to the new RAM.

Is this a compatibility problem ?.

Comment: What does Gigabyte support https://esupport.gigabyte.com/ tell you about mixing memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can not overclock memory on Intels current "Bxxx" motherboards, no matter which memory you buy, it will run at DDR4-2133, the slowest common denominator.

I would not expect any compatibility issues with these low memory frequencies.
It may be possible to overclock to DDR4-2666, but you can't really know until you tried. I would not count on that.

Edit: by the way, there is no "too fast" for memory. All higher end memory can be run at lower frequencies. It's just a waste of money.